# How to install a package using python setup tools?

Tags: python, setuptools, paramiko

I have to install a package using setup tools / egg file in python. Since there will be no internet in factory, it is expected that if we run a setup tool script that package should install on any machine in Linux environment. Help me out in this since I am new to python.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the package to install (as a .tar.gz file) or are you asking how to build a package?

If you have the package, you can simply do:

```
$ pip install /some/path/my_package.1.0.0.tar.gz
```

For how to build a package see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/

If you have dependencies on public packages, you can download them using something like:

```
$ pip install --download /tmp/depend_pkgs some-public-package
```

Then you can put your package and any dependency packages into a folder and install them from it.

A slightly better way would be to put all the packages into a folder tree and use the pip install `--index-url file:///path/my-packages` parameter. The folder tree should be in the PEP 503 [layout](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/), something like:

```
.
├── bar
│   └── bar-0.1.tar.gz
└── foo
    ├── Foo-1.0.tar.gz
    └── Foo-2.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ivo. First I want to build package and then install it which ever machine I want.